# Push data to client, how to handle slow clients?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, client-server

In a push model, where server pushes data to clients, how does one handle clients with low or variable bandwidth?

For example i receive data from a producer and send the data to my clients (push). What if one of my clients decides to download a linux iso, the available bandwidth to this client becomes too little to download my data.

Now when my producers produces data and the server pushes it to the client, all clients will have to wait until all clients have downloaded the data. This is a problem when there is one or more slow clients with little bandwidth.

I can cache the data to be send for every client, but because the data size is big this isn't really an option  (lots of clients * data size = huge memory requirements).

How is this generally solved? No need for code, just a few thoughts/ideas are already more then welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now when my producers produces data and the server pushes it to the
>   client, all clients will have to wait until all clients have
>   downloaded the data.

The above shouldn't be the case -- your clients should be able to download asynchronously from each other, with each client maintaining its own independent download state.  That is, client A should never have to wait for client B to finish, and vice versa.

> I can cache the data to be send for every client, but because the data
>   size is big this isn't really an option (lots of clients * data size =
>   huge memory requirements).

As Warren said in his answer, this problem can be reduced by keeping only one copy of the data rather than one copy per client.  Reference-counting (e.g. via shared_ptr, if you are using C++, or something equivalent in another language) is an easy way to make sure that the shared data is deleted only when all clients are done downloading it.  You can make the sharing more fine-grained, if necessary, by breaking up the data into chunks (e.g. instead of all clients holding a reference to a single 800MB linux iso, you could break it up into 800 1MB chunks, so that you can start removing the earlier chunks from memory as soon as all clients have downloaded them, instead of having to hold the entire 800MB of data in memory until every client has downloaded the entire thing)

Of course, that sort of optimization only gets you so far -- e.g. if two clients each request a different 800MB file, then you're liable to end up with 1.6GB of RAM usage for caching, unless you come up with a more clever solution.

Here are some possible approaches you could try (from less complex to more complex).  You could try any of these either separately or in combination:

1. Monitor how much each client's "backlog" is -- that is, keep a count of the amount of data you have cached waiting to send to that client.  Also keep track of the number of bytes of cached data your server is currently holding; if that number gets too high, force-disconnect the client with the largest backlog, in order to free up memory.  (this doesn't result in a good user experience for the client, of course; but if the client has a buggy or slow connection he was unlikely to have a good user experience anyway.  It does keep your server from crashing or swapping itself to death because a single client has a bad connection)
2. Keep track of how much data your server has cached and waiting to send out.  If the amount of data you have cached is too large (for some appropriate value of "too large"), temporarily stop reading from the socket(s) that are pushing the data out to you (or if you are generating your data internally, temporarily stop generating it).  Once the amount of cached data gets down to an acceptable level again, you can resume receiving (or generating) more data to push.
3. (this may or may not be applicable to your use-case) Revise your data model so that instead of being communications-oriented, it becomes state-oriented.  For example, if your goal is to update the clients' state to match the state of the data-source, and you can organize the data-source's state into a set of key/value pairs, then you can require that the data-source include a key with each piece of data it sends.  Whenever a key/value pair is received from the data-source, simply place that key-value pair into a map (or hash table or some other key/value oriented data structure) for each client (again, used shared_ptr's or similar here to keep memory usage reasonable).  Whenever a given client has drained its queue of outgoing TCP data, remove the oldest item from that client's key/value map, convert it into TCP bytes to send, and add them to the outgoing-TCP-data queue.  Repeat as necessary.  The advantage of this is that "obsolete" values for a given key are automatically dropped inside the server and therefore never need to be sent to the slow clients; rather the slow clients will only ever get the "latest" value for that given key.  The beneficial consequence of that is that a given client's maximum "backlog" will be limited by the number of keys in the state-model, regardless of how slow or intermittent the client's bandwidth is.  Thus a slow client might see fewer updates (per second/minute/hour), but the updates it does see will still be as recent as possible given its bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Cache the data once only, and have each client handler keep track of where it is in the download, all using the same cache.  Once all clients have all the data, the cached data can be deleted.